# Problem Installing spacy for python3.7 mac

Tags: pip, python-3.7, spacy

I'm trying to download spacy to use for python3.7

I tried installing it using pip, and it says the requirement is already satisfied but then when I try to download a dataset (or even just try and import spacy), it says there is no module named spacy! Why is it saying that the requirement is already satisfied when it's not and what should I do about it?

[picture of my terminal with the error (the error is at the very bottom)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0Bvq.jpg)

Comment: Check if it's really there: `ls -ld /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy`. Check if `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages` is in `sys.path`: `python3.7 -c "import sys; print('/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages' in sys.path)"`

Comment: Could be that something's gone corrupt, you're probably best of starting fresh with a clean virtual environment.